# limit of $e^z$ at $\infty$

Tags: complex-analysis

What's the limit of $e^z$ as $z$ approaches infinity?

I am given that the answer is "There is no such limit."

Is this correct, and if so, am I correct to demonstrate this by showing that as $y$ tends to infinity along the $y$-axis, the magnitude of $e^z$ remains $1$, i.e. it doesn't have infinite magnitude, thus it cannot be tending to infinity? And does this mean $e^z$ has an essential singularity at infinity?

Comment: Yes $e^z$ has an essential singularity at infinity.

Comment: @GEdgar Thanks. Is my argument correct?

Comment: You are correct. Consider in particular the sequences $z_n=2in\pi$ and $w_n=n$.

Comment: Another way to see this is to note that the Laurent series of $e^{1/z}$ has infinitely many negative power terms.

Comment: @DanieleA Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the fact: $f$ has a pole of order $k$ at $z=z_0$ if and only if
$$
\lim_{z\to z_0}(z-z_0)^k f(z)=L(\ne 0).
$$

Relpacing $z$ by $\frac 1 z$ and consider the function $f(z)=e^{\frac 1 z}$.
For each $k=0, 1, 2, \ldots $, the limit 
$$
\lim_{z\to 0}z^ke^{\frac 1 z}
$$ 
does not exist (it suffices to check when $z$ is real).

Thus, $f$ has no poles(including removeable singularity) at the origin, and has essential singularity at the origin. 
(or more simply, it can be checked by expanding $f$
as Laurent series-using taylor series formula).

Therefore, $e^z$ has an essential singularity at $\infty$.

Answer (score 4):

If you take two sequences, e.g. $z_n:=n$, and $w_n:=2\pi ni$, then $e^{z_n}\to+\infty$ and $e^{w_n}\equiv 1\to 1$, so $\not\exists\displaystyle\lim_{|z|\to\infty}e^z$.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I did too.