# $e^z$ is entire yet has an essential singularity (at $\infty$)

Tags: complex-analysis

Is there no inconsistency? Or does the property of being entire exclude the point $z=\infty$?

p.s. following up from my previous question [limit of $e^z$ at $\infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/395773/21813)

Comment: An entire function is defined as a function that is holomorphic on $\mathbb C$. Since $\infty$ belongs to the extended plane but not to $\mathbb C$, there is no problem.

Comment: @potato Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The complex plane doesn't contain the point at infinity. (Infinity is *not*a number, not even a complex one.) Entire means holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$. In fact the only functions that are holomorphic on the Riemann sphere (i.e. on $\mathbb{C}\cup \{\infty\}$) are the constant functions.

Comment: Thanks. Your last sentence exactly has also answered the question I was gonna ask next.

Comment: Am I correct that the extended real line adds two points $-\infty$ and $\infty$ to $\mathbb R$, whereas the extended complex plane adds infinitely many points (all those infinitely far from the origin) to $\mathbb C$? (I am aware that the latter are all stereoscopically projected onto the north pole, and are all/each represented by the symbol $\infty$.)